# How to play triplet quarters against quarters

Tags: rhythm, tuplet

I want to know how to count this piece and play it correctly as I don't know how to integrate both hands correctly.

piece:https://musescore.com/user/10943216/scores/7018957

[image: Atonement: Farewell]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing 3 over 2 can be easier if you think in terms of 6 (the common denominator). Then you have

[image]

Here you can see a very regular structure:

[image]

Using this rhythm to you can develop a feel for 3 over 2 by playing or patting this rhythm with your hands and then trying to focus on the triplet pulse of one hand or on the duplet pulse of the other. With time you’ll be able to feel both pulses at the same time.

Comment: I don't really get it, can you elaborate

Comment: @kami Start with this rhythm 1 - 2-and - 3 | 1 - 2-and - 3. The 1,2,3 will be your triplet, the 1,and the duplet.

Comment: I like both your examples - I think they're both exactly the right way to consider the problem - but the 6/12 time signature? Surely 6/8 ?

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS A quarter note triplet in 2/4 is metrically equivalent to 3/6, and if we subdivide each beat 6/12.

Comment: I've only ever seen time signatures with even an number on the bottom - never 6 or 12.

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS It's not a signature, or at least not a common one. But think of it simply as a fraction. A whole note has a length of 1. A quarter note has a length of 1/4. A note in a triplet has a length only two thirds of what its symbol would normally stand for - not 1/4, but 1/6. That's how you squeeze three in the time reserved for only two, if I'm a little comprehensible. So the triplet notes for right hand are 1/6 = 2/12 each, while the non-triplet notes for the left hand are 1/4 = 3/12 each.

Comment: It seems like OP also needs to understand how to play 3 over 4 here, not just 3 over 2.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Don’t think so, in the title the op says triplet quarter against quarter, so I assume hes talking about measure 4.

Answer (score 4):

You have two separate rhythms to coordinate here. The first is beats 1&2 of bars 3 and 5. The second is the quarter notes in bar 4.

Let’s take the quarter notes vs quarter note triplets first. The common denominator between them is 6. That means the quarters land on 1,4 and triplets land on 1,3,5.

The dotted quarter/eighth vs quarter triplets requires doubling the denominator to 12. Eighth notes are in groups of 3’s and quarter triplets are in groups of 4’s. The 8ths land on 1,4,7,10 and the triplets land on 1,5,9. A dotted quarter/eighth would be 1 and 10.

Below is an image showing the notated rhythm with red dots showing the subdivisions. I used only 2 beats to demonstrate. Count the subdivisions and feel where the pulses lie and you will get the feel for playing those rhythms simultaneously.

[image]